# bus properties settings ignored

Tags: java, cxf

I had cxf.xml file:

```
<beans ....

<cxf:bus>
    <cxf:features>
        <cxf:logging/>
    </cxf:features>
</cxf:bus>
</beans>
```

but during some operations, i got error:

```
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Unmarshalling Error: Maximum Number of Child Elements limit (50000) Exceeded
```

and I found out that it can be overridden with org.apache.cxf.stax.maxChildElements value. So i first tried putting org.apache.cxf.stax.maxChildElements=120000 in gradle, in IDEA arguments, which didnt work, so i modified my .xml file like this:

```
<cxf:bus>
    <cxf:features>
        <cxf:logging/>
    </cxf:features>
    <cxf:properties>
        <entry key="org.apache.cxf.stax.maxChildElements" value="120000"/>
    </cxf:properties>
</cxf:bus>
```

but none of this worked, and I am currently without ideas, as of why this setting is not getting registered.

Im working with libraries *cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws* and *cxf-rt-transports-http* both on version 3.2.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try doing configuration via java code as well.

You can get Bus instance which is used for creating your `org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Client`:

```
    YourActual service = //return instance of your @WebService class by defining address & interpreter;
    Client client=ClientProxy.getClient(service);
    client.getBus().setProperty(StaxUtils.MAX_CHILD_ELEMENTS,120000)
```

Or if you have your endpoint implementor then you can do :

```
Bus bus=BusFactory.getDefaultBus();
bus.setProperty(StaxUtils.MAX_CHILD_ELEMENTS,120000);

Object implementor = <Your service implementation class>;
EndpointImpl ep = (EndpointImpl) Endpoint.publish(yourendpoint, implementor);
ep.setBus(bus);
```

Above Bus configuration psudo-code taken from [CXF doc](https://cxf.apache.org/docs/bus-configuration.html).

Answer (score 1):

If when you say "IDEA Arguments" you mean this box (labeled: Program Arguments)...

[image]

Try instead enabling Modify Options -> Add VM Options

[image]

Then write your VM Option string in the box labeled VM options.
try

```
-Dorg.apache.cxf.stax.maxChildElements=1000000
```

[image]

This may or may not work depending on what you meant by IDEA Arguments.  I have had IDEA ignore many options that I have tried to pass to the JVM via the "Program Arguments" box at work.  Hopefully this resolves your issue.  If this fails, I will try to monitor this thread.